# What does the "undefined reference to varName" in C mean?

Tags: c, reference, undefined

I have 2 files: `a.c` and `b.c`

In `a.c` I am sending a signal to a function located in `b.c`

```
signal(SIGUSR1,doSomething);
```

On top of the a.c file, I have:

```
extern void doSomething (int    sig);
```

When I compile, however, I get an error:

> /tmp/ccCw9Yun.o: In function `main':
>
>   a.c:(.text+0xba): undefined reference to`doSomething'
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

The following headers are included:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Please show your header (`.h`) files.

Comment: Is `doSomething` actually defined in `b.c`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to link both `a.o` and `b.o`:

```
gcc -o program a.c b.c
```

---

If you have a `main()` in each file, you cannot link them together.

However, your `a.c` file contains a reference to `doSomething()` and expects to be linked with a source file that defines `doSomething()` and does not define any function that is defined in `a.c` (such as `main()`).

You cannot call a function in Process B from Process A.  You cannot send a signal to a function; you send signals to processes, using the `kill()` system call.

The `signal()` function specifies which function in your current process (program) is going to handle the signal when your process receives the signal.

You have some serious work to do understanding how this is going to work - how ProgramA is going to know which process ID to send the signal to.  The code in `b.c` is going to need to call `signal()` with `dosomething` as the signal handler.  The code in `a.c` is simply going to send the signal to the other process.

Comment: The thing is .. a.c and b.c each define each own main function. Compiling .o files result in a error multiple definition of `main'

Comment: @mac Well, you need to link them together if one is going to depend on functions in the other; if they have duplicate functions you need to resolve it somehow (maybe pull `doSomething` out into a third file that `a.c` and `b.c` both depend on)

Comment: I got it. Instead of using signal ()... i used kill(pid_to_send_signal_to, handler);

Comment: The first line of this answer inspired me to the solution. In large programs with Makefiles, make sure to include every source file you newly create!

Answer (score 10):

It is very bad style to define external interfaces in .c files. .

You should do this

a.h

```
    extern void doSomething (int    sig);
```

a.c

```
    void doSomething (int    sig)
    {
       ... do stuff 
    }
```

b.c

```
#include "a.h"
.....
signal(SIGNAL, doSomething);
```

.

Answer (score 4):

An initial reaction to this would be to ask and ensure that the two object files are being linked together. This is done at the compile stage by compiling both files at the same time:

```
gcc -o programName a.c b.c
```

Or if you want to compile separately, it would be:

```
gcc -c a.c
gcc -c b.c
gcc -o programName a.o b.o
```

Answer (score 3):

You're getting a linker error, so your extern is working (the compiler compiled `a.c` without a problem), but when it went to link the object files together at the end it couldn't resolve your extern -- `void doSomething(int);` wasn't actually found anywhere. Did you mess up the extern? Make sure there's actually a `doSomething` defined in `b.c` that takes an `int` and returns `void`, and make sure you remembered to include `b.c` in your file list (i.e. you're doing something like `gcc a.c b.c`, not just `gcc a.c`)

Answer (score 3):

You need to compile and then link the object files like this:

```
gcc -c a.c  
gcc -c b.c  
gcc a.o b.o -o prog
```

Answer (score 1):

make sure your doSomething function is not static.