# Continuous "undefined reference to..."

Tags: c, function, undefined-reference

I'm working on a program and I keep getting "undefined reference to 'dosell' " and I can't quite figure out what is going on. Here's the declaration of the function:

```
void dosell(int *cash, int *numchips);
```

The use of the function:

```
choice = menu();

// Execute the appropriate choice.
if (choice == 1) {
    dobuy(&cash, &numchips);
}
else if (choice == 2) {
    dosell(&cash, &numchips);
}
```

And the function itself:

```
void dosell(int *cash, int *numchips) {

   int numsell;

   // Determine the number of chips to be sold.
   printf("How many chips do you want to sell?\n");
   scanf("%d", &numsell);

   // Print out the error message if this is too much.
   if (numsell > *numchips)
       printf("Sorry, you do not have that many chips. No chips sold.\n");

   // Execute the transaction.
    else {
       (*cash) += sellchips(numsell);
       (*numchips) -= numsell;
}}}
```

Comment: Is `void dosell(int *cash, int *numchips)` declared or defined **ABOVE** where it is called using `else if (choice == 2) ... dosell(&cash, &numchips);`?

Comment: Is `dosell()` in the same file as the call to it?  If not, are you linking both (all) the files to create the program?  What's with the `}}}` at the end; it looks like a syntax error, unless you've accidentally managed to use a GCC extension -- nested functions.  Can you show the exact error message?  Is it a linker error or a compiler error?

Comment: This is a linker error. The linker misses the object providing the definition/implementation of `dosell()`. So prototyping, declaring isn't the issue here, dear fellow commenters, as those latter tweaks calm don the compiler only.

Comment: Related (if not a duplicate): http://stackoverflow.com/q/5892056/694576

Comment: @alk: related, yes - it covers the general case.  Duplicate: I think not.  At the moment, I'm pinning hopes on the `}}}` being the solution -- it means that the `dosell()` function is defined inside, and hence only accessible from, some other function that is not the function calling `dosell()`.  But we really need the OP to confirm that he's using GCC (or perhaps `clang`/LLVM working compatibly with GCC), and whether there is a a typo in the question or the code at this point.

Comment: Thank you Jonathan. I took a look at the `}}}` and what turns out is one of those was misplaced. On of brackets should have been at the end of the "dobuy" function, which is immediately before the "dosell." Because of this, it included the "dosell" within the "dobuy" so it was as if I hadn't even written the "dosell" function.

Comment: Now you know why indentation is important.  If you'd seen the nested function indented, you'd have known there was something up.

Answer (score 0):

Put a declaration of the function at the beginning of the file i.e. before the main function and after the includes and defines:

```
void dosell(int *cash, int *numchips) ;
```

Comment: Good guess, but until the OP provides enough information to confirm that is the issue, perhaps a tad premature... No downvote, but just a helpful suggestion.

Comment: The declaration is mentioned in the question.

Comment: Please see my comment on the OP.

Comment: Sorry! The whole declaration is BEFORE the main function, the use of it, (the second section of code) is inside the main, and the function itself is after.

Answer (score 0):

<sup>*Transferring key comments into an answer*</sup>

Is `dosell()` in the same file as the call to it? If not, are you linking both (all) the files to create the program?

What's with the `}}}` at the end of `dosell()`; it looks like a syntax error, unless you've accidentally managed to use a GCC extension — [nested functions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.1/gcc/Nested-Functions.html#Nested-Functions).

It actually takes quite a bit of effort to make GCC give you a warning about a nested function.  You can do it by specifying a standard such as `-std=c11` and `-pedantic`.  However, you should not plan on using nested functions, especially not by accident.

> I took a look at the `}}}` and what turns out is one of those was misplaced. One of brackets should have been at the end of the `dobuy()` function, which is immediately before the `dosell()` function. Because of this, it included `dosell()` within `dobuy()`, so it was as if I hadn't even written the `dosell()` function.

I observe that if your code had been indented by an automatic indenter, you would have seen that the start line for `dosell()` was indented, which would perhaps have tipped you off that there was something amiss.  The symptoms you describe are exactly consistent with a nested function.