# "undefined reference" error when using c header files

Tags: c, gcc, header-files, undefined-reference

I have three files: `main.c`, `location.c` and `location.h`. They can't seem to compile.

Here are my source files.
main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "location.h"

int main() {
    executeLook();
    return 0;
}
```

location.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void executeLook() {
    print("Hello World");
}
```

location.h:

```
extern void executeLook();
```

On compiling the CodeBlocks(gcc compiler) compiler gives the following error:

```
c:\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\8.2.0\..\..\..\..\mingw32\bin\ld.exe: I:\Test Program\main.o: main.c|| undefined reference to `executeLook'|
```

Anyone able to help me out? I'm really stuck on this.

Comment: Actually, that dupe is a C++ question, although the principles still apply. A better C dupe is here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5892056/10077

Comment: Unfortunately, "compiling" is an overloaded term used to describe the complete build process.  The error you are seeing is not a compiler error at all.